# How can I have AVSpeechSynthesizer speak multiple languages in the same string?

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

How can I have AVSpeechSynthesizer speak multiple languages using two different voices in the same string? For example, I would like the synthesizer to say: "I like to say *hola* instead of hello."

I would prefer that didFinishSpeechUtterance not be called until the complete sentence is spoken.

Comment: In the context of strings, "hola" is not equal to "hello", please look into NSLocalizedString().

Comment: I understand that. I was not giving an example of a string, I am giving an example of what I want the speech synthesizer to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can mix languages in a single utterance. You'll have to break it into pieces and play them separately.

Comment: Will didFinishSpeechUtterance get called each time the language is changed or can it finish the whole sentence and then call that function?

Comment: I suspect it will be called for each speech fragment you send to it to speak, but the best way to find out is to test it.